# SSD- Ubuntu 20.04 kernel panic mode on the 5th day,

Tags: 20.04, kernel, uefi, ssd

```
'# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>'
'# / was on /dev/nvme1n1p2 during installation'
'UUID=dcf15593-4afa-4381-8d3f-7be280b0d955 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1'
'# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme1n1p1 during installation'
'UUID=B97A-EC82  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1'
'/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0'
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used      Priority
/swapfile                               file        2097148 0   -2
```

sysctl vm.swappiness

```
vm.swappiness=60
```

I have been using Ubuntu for the past 4 days, and today during shutdown the computer stalled for 5 minutes and displayed the attached outputs. I have checked online forums and found this articles which basically says it is a issue related to power saving (APST), so adding a kernel parameter should disable the APST and I won't see that output anymore.

However, I wonder why I started to get this output on the 5th day of my Ubuntu adventure? I was using Xubuntu and windows before than I formatted the disk and installed Ubuntu on it.

When I run `smartctl -H /dev/nvme0n1` I get

```
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

So my SSD seems healthy, but why do I get this message? Should I replace my SSD? Is the system is improperly installed?

- 2 months update

- By following @heynnema 's direction, I was able to solve my issue. Checking ssd slot fit and checking or firmware update did help.

Comment: Let me know if this happens again. This sounds like it could just be a one-off thing.

Comment: Looks like your SSD encountered an error during shutdown that caused it to prematurely unmount. Whatever the error was, it occurred before the log you posted so we don't know anything about it. I see no indication that your system is improperly installed, nor that your SSD is defective. If it happens again, more troubleshooting might be possible.

Comment: @DrewHowdenTech It happened again. I used my computer for an hour, browsed the web and then I see the same messages.

Comment: @user535733 How can I run some troubleshooting for this issue?

Comment: The starting point is the *exact* wording and timing of all error messages. Also check  /var/log/syslog for events that occurred around the time the problem began. Developers intend error messages and logs to be useful -- they are not deliberately cryptic. Perhaps you have the same problem, perhaps you are encountering a different problem with some of the same symptoms -- keep an open mind.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*` and screenshots of the `Disks` app **SMART Data & Tests** data window. This window is scrollable so it may take two screenshots. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Do you know how to `fsck` your Ubuntu disk partition?

Comment: You may have to `grep -i nvme /var/log/syslog*` if my previous command shows no output.

Comment: @heynnema Hi, thanks for the help! I have added the screenshots that you asked for

Comment: Thanks for the data. Also show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. I've rewritten my answer, so go ahead and do it, and report back.

Comment: How did you *"I formatted the disk and installed Ubuntu"*? Specifically the **formatted** part.

Comment: @heynnema I basically picked the "Erase the disk and install ubuntu" option on the installer. And I have installed Arch linux before ubuntu. For doing that I had to use gdisk and delete all partitions. But none of the formats were something like -overwrite the data-.

Comment: @heynnema I added the free -h and sysctl vm.swappiness to my answer.

Comment: @heynnema I could not run the commands with /swapfile in ti because it said there is no such a directory or file...

Comment: @heynnema you can find the outputs for the swapon and ls -al / commands at the top of my question

Comment: @heynnema hey, I am experiencing this problem again. I have updated the pictures for your consideration. Yesterday night and also today I got these messages

Comment: @mansurlinux That's a failure mode that we didn't see before. There's a problem with your nvme SSD. Is this a desktop or laptop computer?

Comment: @heynnema it's a laptop. My ssd is  1 TB M.2 Kingston A2000 | PCIe 3.0 x4 | NVMe

Comment: @heynnema Ok so little bit more information about it. I got 2 ssd, one is running Windows and the other is running Ubuntu. Windows is installed on Samsung evo 970, and ubuntu on Kingston. Initially this SSD was named as nvme0n1 but after windows installation it got nvme1n1. If this nvme is defect, I can replace it as the last option...

Comment: @mansurlinux Download the `Samsung Magician` and check the firmware on the evo 970. Go to the Kingston web site and look for a similar updater app to check the firmware on the Kingston. If you're  brave, re-seat the Kingston in its slot. Make sure it's pushed all the way in. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema Samsung SSD only runs Windows and there is nothing on it about linux. But windows boot partition is on the Kingston. Do you think Samsung Magician can fix something like this? Also, Kingston does not offer any program for linux, just for windows. I can check the slot on Monday, it's not a big deal. But it should be good because I got this laptop 3 months ago and the problems about my SSD started after I installed Ubuntu

Comment: @mansurlinux I only mentioned the Samsung because they have a quick and easy app to check their firmware. It's a Windows app. If Kingston has a similar Windows app, then download both and check their firmware. The slot issue is a strong candidate for a possible fix, esp if it's not fully pushed into its socket. Does your /etc/fstab use UUIDs? I ask before I suggest a different way to troubleshoot this.

Comment: @heynnema Oh ok, so I need to install both software to windows and then check the SSDs! Cool.For the other question, I added the information `/etc/fstab` information ot the question

Comment: @heynnema Ok, so I guess I found the issue. I haven't been getting these error messages during shutdown for the last 2 days. The only difference was, I havent activated my VPN. But when I connect to VPN, I get these message on shutdown...

Comment: @mansurlinux VPN has nothing to do with NVMe errors. Did you check that the Kingston is properly inserted into its socket? Did you check the NVMe's firmware?

Comment: @heynnema I havent had chance to check the ssd socket, but for firmware aspect, everything seems normal....

Comment: @mansurlinux The `Samsung Magician`, and the Kingston equivalent, showed no updates required?

Comment: @heynnema  I have checked Kingston, it said there is no update and the SSD is healthy. But I forgot to check Samsung. However, when I do not activate my VPN connection, I do not get any errors like that.

Comment: @mansurlinux Pure coincidence. If the Kingston has a poor connection to it's socket, it could fail/work at any time.

Comment: @heynnema SSD has a good fit with its socket, on Monday I will work with VPN again, I will let you know if I get this error again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first check your Ubuntu file system for errors...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode

In the `terminal` app:

- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1`
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n2`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

Let's increase your /swapfile from 2G to 4G and see if that helps...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 16G RAM and 4G swap
```

<strike>Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.</strike>

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**Update #2:**

In reviewing new log files, nvme1 (Kingston) has a problem. It looks like it needs to be re-seated in its socket. Make sure it's pushed all the way in. Also need to check the firmware.

Comment: I am waiting for my friend to bring my USB then I will do these steps, thanks!

Comment: @mansurlinux I added Update #1 to my answer.

Comment: I could not run the commands with /swapfile in ti because it said there is no such a directory or file...

Comment: @mansurlinux It should be there, it's in your /etc/fstab. Edit your question and show me `swapon -s` and `ls -al /`.

Comment: @mansurlinux The swapfile is there. Did you manually type in the commands shown in Update #1, or did you copy/paste them as I recommended?

Comment: I copied and pasted it, but I guess I should do it on my installation, not on the live cd... Sorry!

Comment: @mansurlinux Correct.

Comment: now it did work! Thanks.

Comment: but how did it solve the kernel panic issue?

Comment: @mansurlinux We don't know 100% until you test it more. Small /swapfiles are common problems for problems similar to yours. Have you done the `fsck` yet on both partitions?

Comment: yes I did sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p1 and also sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p2 on the live usb

Comment: @mansurlinux Did `fsck` find/repair any problems?

Comment: I have added the outputs of the fsck commands. And I will mark it as an answer if I dont see that kernel messages on tomorrow as well!

Comment: @mansurlinux Status please...